# How can I use split() and the calculate the mean of certain column?

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to split the mtcars dataframe into list by using split() function and i want to ssplit using cyl column. Then I want to calculate the mean of each of the dataframe in the resulting list (example: mean of '8' dataframe in the list). How can I do it? I am beginner in R so need easy to understand solution please. My code:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `split` first, you need to apply the mean to each of your subsets; you can do that with `*apply` functions. Here `sapply` takes as input the list of subsets and apply to every one the function `function(x) mean(x$mpg)`.

```r
split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl) |>
  sapply(function(x) mean(x$mpg))
```

A short version with `tapply`:

```r
tapply(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl, mean)

#       4        6        8 
#26.66364 19.74286 15.10000
```